# Websites that provide a C# or Java development environment?

Tags: c#, java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I'm searching for a website that provides a development envirment for C# or Java programing.

Are you familiar with one?
Please add known bugs that you aware of,and for C#:for what VS version is that equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: You need c# or java hosting providers or something like assembla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) and Editors](http://apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/IDEs.html)

[Open Source IDEs in C#](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/ides)